# Keep the session alive in Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

I have some synchronization process going on in the terminal in Debian 8 machine over the internet and I anticipate it to keep running for the whole night.

If I'm idle for few minutes, I get kicked out of the session and needs to log in again with the password which might hamper the work.

How can I keep myself logged in even if I don't have any other work going on besides in the terminal? I will have the power outlet plugged in to the machine surely.

Comment: stop autoidle or the daemon which kicks out users.

Comment: How to do that? I'm not very familiar with the Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your synchronization process is running within a terminal, you should take a look at `tmux` or `screen` for virtual persistent terminals. 
For more informations you could read [tmux manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) and [screen manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).

Comment: How do you happen to know anything about the system settings?

Comment: Just read the manual pages of your distribution, or read a well explained wiki. If you want some help with this, you could take a look at the Debian Wiki here : https://wiki.debian.org/